# Difference between functions choice and choices and when to use one over the other

Tags: python

What's the difference between the outputs of choice and choices? When do you use one over the other?

```
test = [1,2,3]

print(random.choices(test))

[1]

print(random.choice(test))

1
```

Answer (score 3):

[`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) supports returning multiple results (which is why the result is an array) based on additional parameters like `weights`. For example (taken from the manual):

```
choices(['red', 'black', 'green'], [18, 18, 2], k=6)
```

While [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) returns a random single result from the list.

For more see:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html